# Clojure: No implementation of method in protocol

Tags: java, clojure, lisp, rdf

I am trying to load the Clojure library for RDF [clj-plaza](http://github.com/antoniogarrote/clj-plaza/) in Clojure REPL like so:

```
user=> (use 'plaza.rdf.core)
nil
```

I have a folder named plaza, and a subfolder named rdf and the file core.clj available and as far as I can tell, Clojure REPL loads the library as it should.

Now, if I do

```
user=> (alter-root-rdf-ns “http://www.example.org/”)
"http://www.example.org"
```

And again, as far as I can tell the core.clj library is reporting as it should.
Now I do

```
(def e (document-to-model “http://www.snee.com/rdf/elvisimp.rdf” :xml))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :load-stream of protocol: #’plaza.rdf.core/RDFModel found for class: nil (NO_SOURCE_FILE:2)
```

I get the same result if I try f.ex.

```
(make-triples [["http://triple1" "http://triple2" "http://triple3"]])
```

In the source code [(core.clj)](http://github.com/antoniogarrote/clj-plaza/blob/master/src/plaza/rdf/core.clj) there is a method called load-stream in the protocol RDFModel

```
(defprotocol RDFModel
  "Operations for the manipulation of RDF"
  ....
  (load-stream [model stream format] "Load triples from a stream")
  ....
```

And load-stream is implemented

```
(defn document-to-model
  "Adds a set of triples read from a serialized document into a model"
  ([stream format]
    (load-stream *rdf-model* stream format)))
```

I can't really seem to pinpoint what is wrong here, in the source code it all seems to add up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(defn document-to-model ...)` snippet does not implement `load-stream`; it implements a function called `document-to-model` which calls `load-stream` with a bunch of arguments, the first of which -- `*rdf-model*` -- needs to be of a type to which the `RDFModel` protocol has been extended (or which implements the protocol or the corresponding interface directly).

`clj-plaza` provides two implementations of `RDFModel`, in the namespaces `plaza.rdf.implementations.sesame` (see `(deftype SesameModel ...`, [line 218](http://github.com/antoniogarrote/clj-plaza/blob/master/src/plaza/rdf/implementations/sesame.clj#L218) in the source) and `plaza.rdf.implementations.jena` (see `(deftype JenaModel ...`, [line 167](http://github.com/antoniogarrote/clj-plaza/blob/master/src/plaza/rdf/implementations/jena.clj#L167)). `require`-ing them should be enough to pull in said implementations; then you can use them with `*rdf-model*`s of appropriate type.

Comment: Marczyk I have a similar problem but I get "No implementation of method: :is-literal of protocol: #’plaza.rdf.core/RDFNode found for class: Keyword. I required both plaza.rdf.implementations.sesame and plaza.rdf.implementations.jena. I'll start another question if you need more details.

Comment: @aduric: It seems that you're using a keyword someplace where a type implementing `RDFNode` is expected -- possibly in a call to `alter-root-model` or `with-model`? If you can't find a problematic spot like that, I guess a separate question with more details would be useful. (NB. I haven't looked at clj-plaza in a while, so if there's some common gotcha involved here, I might be missing it.)

Answer (score 1):

one more step after (require... is to (init-jena-framework) or (init-sesame-framework).